# In which Lifecycle method I have to call my action creator for checking if user authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have an app where user authentications data stored in localStorage. In my app component, I have rotes, which are unavailable for unauthenticated users. When user visit the page, in App component script calls action creator function and checks if the user has data in local storage, and if he has, the data goes to my redux store, so in that way he is going to be authenticated. But there is some problem. When user is in rote that is unavailable for unatuthenticated users and refreshes the page, so the App component going to be rendered the first time and the first time still the user is unauthenticated because there is not auth data in my redux store, action creator going to be runned in constructor, but the redux props still will not come to my Component, and in the component it checks and understand that user is unauthenticated and redirects to main rote, and then redux data comes, and so the user already authenticated, but he isnt in the page, where he was.[The routes in app component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31K9u.png)

[The action creator, which checking and automate authenticating the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUODM.png)

[Order of actions in console. (Please look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovmV8.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if user authenticated and invoke your action onAuthAuth 
 in componentDidMount life cycle and since it's async call you should render loader/spinner.
once you received your data, here you have 2 cases:
1. The user is authenticated then you can stop the loader and render your App component for authenticated users. you can add flag isLogout to your store and if it's false and your data from localstorage exist you can know that is authenticated.
2. the user is unauthenticated, isLogout true the stop the loader and navigate to login page.

let me know if it's helped you

Comment: My dear Gilad. I find your advice useful, and came to this conclusion. Do you think a good solution? I added to my redux store a flag "autoAuthFinished" by default is false and only becomes true when my "autoAuth" actoin is finished, and every time my app component is mounted, I invoke my "autoAuth" action. And in my app component I check if autoAuthFinished is true, check if the user is authed, show some routes, otherwise show other rotes. If autoAuthFinished is false, I show the spinner. How is my solution in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Another option Since your action only provide some data you can use selector instead of action, connect your app with connect HOC and in mapStateToprops
get  boolean if user is authenticated

```
const mapStateToprops = (state) => {
  isAuth: getIsAuth()
}

const getIsAuth = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) {
        return false;
    }
    const expirationDate = newDate(localStorage.getItem('expirationDate');
    if (// !expired ) {
        return true; 
    }

    return false;
}
```